# Django urls.py mechanism

Tags: python, django

Recently I started my web project using Django with reference to some youtube tutorials. I have created a project named *admin* and created an app named *user*. From many tutorials they have created separate `urls.py` for both *project* and *app*. But in my case only the *project*'s `urls.py` is working.

For example, I have defined the *index* view (my home page) in *project*'s `urls.py` and *login* view in *app*'s `urls.py`. When I try to access the login as it shows:

```
The current path, login, didn't match any of these
```

Can anyone help me to find out the solution for this?

Comment: Did you include the logins, etc.?

Comment: put some code to understand what you have done sa far

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views

Comment: Yes I have included login. My question was how the two urls.py are working

Comment: Post your urls if you hope to get any help.

Comment: Put your code and your files hierarchy please !!!

Answer (score 2):

Django only checks the URLs of the project's [`ROOT_URLCONF`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#root-urlconf) e.g. `urls.py`. If you want to include the URLs of a certain app, you can do the following:

In your projects `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/', include('user.urls')),
    # others...
]
```

Then, if you go to url `yoursite.com/user/`, it will find the URLs specified in the app's `urls.py`. For more information see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs).

Also make sure that your app `user` is in the `INSTALLED_APPS` of your `settings.py`, like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    'user',
    ...
]
```

So that django knows about your app.